# How to test express middleware error handler with jest and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, ts-jest

I'm completely new to testing middleware with jest

The middleware

```
import HttpException from "../common/http-exception";
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";

export const errorHandler = (
  error: HttpException,
  request: Request,
  response: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  const status = error.statusCode || error.status || 500;

  response.status(status).send(error);
};
```

The broken test giving the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

```
import HttpException from "../src/common/http-exception";
import { NextFunction, Request, Response, response } from "express";
import { errorHandler } from "../src/middleware/error.middleware";

describe("Error handler middleware", () => {
  const error: HttpException = {
    name: "error",
    statusCode: 500,
    status: 1,
    message: "string",
    error: "string"
  };
  let mockRequest: Partial<Request>;
  let mockResponse: Partial<Response>;
  let nextFunction: NextFunction = jest.fn();

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockRequest = {};
    mockResponse = {
      status: jest.fn()
    };
  });

  test("handle error", async () => {
    errorHandler(
      error as HttpException,
      mockRequest as Request,
      mockResponse as Response,
      nextFunction
    );

    expect(response).toBe(500);
  });
});
```

And the typescript for HttpException

```
export default class HttpException extends Error {
  statusCode?: number;
  status?: number;
  message: string;
  error: string | null;

  constructor(statusCode: number, message: string, error?: string) {
    super(message);

    this.statusCode = statusCode;
    this.message = message;
    this.error = error || null;
  }
}
```

Comment: The request and the response *are* undefined, you have the `let`s but never any *values*.

Comment: I want the value of response to come from the middleware is that possible?

Comment: How? You're calling it directly with (the undefined) mockResponse, where would any other value come from?

Comment: Itried with   beforeEach(() => {
    mockRequest = {};
    mockResponse = {
      status: jest.fn()
    };
  });

Comment: OK, please [edit] the question to update what's now happening. Think about how the response is actually *used*.

Comment: Thanks, @jonrsharpe I've edited and shown the new error

Comment: Again, think about how the response is used - what does your test double of the response's status method return?

Comment: It should return the error and error is defined with a const???

Comment: No. Read the middleware code; `response.status` doesn't return the error, the error is an *argument*.

Comment: and this is why I'm getting  `Cannot read property 'send' of undefined` ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In you handler, you call `response.status(status).send(error);`, this mean `.status()` should return an object what include `send` function, but in your mock `status: jest.fn()` it will return `undefined`.

With express's Response object, it is using chain methods, this mean the function will return the object itself.

We can mock the same behavior with `.mockReturnThis()`.

I also update your expectations for your middleware:

.spec.ts

```
describe("Error handler middleware", () => {
  const error: HttpException = {
    name: "error",
    statusCode: 500,
    status: 1,
    message: "string",
    error: "string"
  };
  let mockRequest: Partial<Request>;
  let mockResponse: Partial<Response>;
  let nextFunction: NextFunction = jest.fn();

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockRequest = {};
    mockResponse = {
      status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(), // This line
      send: jest.fn(), // also mocking for send function
    };
  });

  test("handle error when error includes statusCode", async () => {
    errorHandler(
      error as HttpException,
      mockRequest as Request,
      mockResponse as Response,
      nextFunction
    );

    expect(mockResponse.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(500);
    expect(mockResponse.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith(error);
    expect(nextFunction).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```